# Crop Imageview and apply Rounded Corner with Textview

Tags: android, shapes, rounded-corners, clip

[image: Crop Imageview and apply Rounded Corner]

Kindly help me on this to crop the imageview and textview with rounded corner in android. (Eg: Attached sample image)

Answer (score 2):

You can try using `CardView` with `app:cardCornerRadius` equal to 1/2 of the height of the view.

Answer (score 0):

If your min version allows it you can use a ViewOutlineProvider.

You can apply this to any kind of view meaning you can just put your image and text in a layout and make the circular clipping on the layout.

```
view.clipToOutline = true
view.outlineProvider = object : ViewOutlineProvider()
{
   @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
   override fun getOutline(view: View, outline: Outline) {
       outline.setOval(0, 0, view.width, view.height);
   }
}
```